# Why is this button aligned differently in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, layout

Given [this HTML page](https://codepen.io/jameshfisher/pen/VwzYOOq):

```
<html>
<body>before<button style="height: 100px"></button>after</body>
</html>
```

The page layout is very different in Chrome and Firefox. Here's Firefox:

[image: layout in Firefox]

Here's Chrome:

[image: layout in Chrome]

In Chrome, the button seems to follow `vertical-align: baseline`. But in Firefox, it seems to follow `vertical-align: middle`, or something like that.

**What is causing this layout difference? And which browser is in the right, regarding CSS specs?**

Comment: both are following baseline but Firefox is calculating the baseline differently. add one letter inside the button to see that Firefox is considering the baseline like that. IMO Chrome is the correct one here but buttons are always strange so I am not surprised with such behavior

Comment: Agree with Temani, but even Chrome's behaviour doesn't seem correct. If the button contains a single empty block element, that shouldn't be sufficient to move the baseline, but in Chrome it moves it to the middle, to match Firefox. In any case, a button with no contents is a really bad idea which you shouldn't be doing, so in practice it makes little difference.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, every browser handles the predefined HTML styles in a different way. There's not really a "correct" way for browsers to go about these things, as it's technically up to them to decide how they would like to define the styles.

On both browsers, it seemed that `vertical-align: bottom` worked the same. If that was your intended goal that might be worth considering. I also found a post stating that you could include [this](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) CSS file, so that also might be worth a try. Hopefully, that helps some!